# How do I read a line after the 12000th character?

Tags: java

I have a little Java problem. (I think it is little...)

I have got a HUGE text-file with a specified line-length. I KNOW the first 12000 characters do not hold the information I am seeking for. Lines end with "\r\n".

How do I jump to the 12001th position and then read the next line?

Thanks for help!

Comment: 12000th character, or 12000th byte? That makes a huge difference in feasibility.

Comment: What is the encoding of that text file?  If it is UTF-8 then 1 to 3 bytes per character.  Or if it is UTF-16 then 2 to 4 bytes.

Comment: I don't know witch UTF it is. Standard Numbers and characters are included. How Do I find out? The end is an \r\n from the last line.

Comment: Some editors, like [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/), display the file encoding when you open the file in that editor. For example, if you open a UTF-8 encoded file in _Notepad++_, it displays **UTF-8** in its status bar. Also, you wrote that the file has a specified line length. Does that mean each line in the file is the same length? If yes, then is that length measured by the number of characters in each line?

Comment: Notepad says UTF-8. I did not write the file, but i was told, that each line has got 24 characters. that includes that "\r\n".

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is `skip()`

> Skips characters. This method will block until some characters are available, an I/O error occurs, or the end of the stream is reached.

It is available in `java.io.Reader` and its subclasses.
Since `Reader` class is abstract, you will probably be using `class FileReader` for your purpose.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#skip-long-

Comment: @Tagamoga Did this help?